# Recursive function exponential function

Tags: javascript, function, recursion, taylor-series

I need implement recursive function exponential function (e^x) with help row Taylor:
e^x = 1 + x + x2/2! + x3/3! + ...
But i can't understand what i do wrong
I have next code:

```
function fact(n){
    return n * fact(n - 1);
}

function myPow(x, n){
    return x * myPow(x, n - 1);
}

function expon(x ,n){
    if(n == 1){
        return expon(x, n - 1) * x;
    }
    else{
        return expon(x, n - 1) + (myPow(x, n)/fact(n));
    }

}

console.log(expon(1, 10));
```

Comment: Your factorial function has no boundary. You should include an if statement there when `n == 1` to return 1. Otherwise it's going to continue indefinitely.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the expon function will go for infinity. You need to have another if else statement that says when n =  0 then return 1 because e^0 = 1 and then it will return all the way up the chain recursively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should look like this:

```
function fact(n){
  if (n == 1)
    return 1;
  return n * fact(n - 1);
}

function myPow(x, n){
  if(n == 1)
    return n;
  return x * myPow(x, n - 1);
}

function expon(x ,n){
  if(n == 1){
    return 1;
  }
  else{
    return expon(x, n - 1) + (myPow(x, n)/fact(n));
  }

console.log(expon(1, 10));
```

Comment: I add it but, but it didn't fix problem. I have next error in consol: 
"Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded"

Comment: I forgot to mention the if stament in the myPow method.

Comment: @S.Hagvin you should mark this as the answer since it works for you

Comment: Jonas Meinerz sorry I didn't know it. I only learn this resource

Answer (score 1):

Your factorial function has no base case.

```
function fact(n) {
  if (n == 1)
    return 1;
  if (n < 1)
    return 0;
  return n * fact(n - 1);
}
```

A similar change will be needed for `myPow`. Although since powers are funny, I think if n == 0 return 1.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an assignment so I won't debug your code but give you some hints.

You seem to not understand how recursion ends with giving a result in the end.

You have to provide a simple case where you return a value with a non recursive call.

Sometimes you don't write any `if` (bad!), and sometimes there is an `if`, but both cases use a recursive call.

Answer (score 0):

This will solve your problem:

```
function fact(n) {
  if (n == 1) return 1;
  return n * fact(n - 1);
}

function myPow(x, n) {
  if (n == 0) return 1;
  return x * myPow(x, n - 1);
}

function expon(x, n) {
  if (n == 0) return 1;
  return expon(x, n - 1) + myPow(x, n) / fact(n);
}
console.log(expon(1, 10));
```